# TextBox.TextChanged event limited to 32000 chars?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a Windows Phone App which uses the clipboard to exchange large texts by using the TextBox Pasting-Function of the OnScreen-Keyboard.

For me it looks like if there is a 32000 chars limit.

```
PasteTextBox.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(OnTextChanged);
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CounterTextBlock.Text = PasteTextBox.Text.Length.ToString();
}
```

The code crashes if I'm pasting more than 32000 chars into the TextBox.
`TextBox.MaxLength` is `0` (unlimited), increasing it didn't help.

Is this a technical limit or what can I do to prevent the crash?

Update: Maybe I have explained bad. I try again:
There can be a large amount of text in the clipboard, which I want to import into the app. Clipboard.GetText is blocked on Windows-Phone, so I go the detour over the textbox to get the text. It works fine if clipboard text is <= 32000.

Update2: Hm, I'm not sure what's going on after @f14shm4n wrote it would work.
Here my full example:

```
    private void ApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText("... Long Text with 1000 Chars ...");
        PasteTextBox.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(OnTextChanged);
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CounterTextBlock.Text = PasteTextBox.Text.Length.ToString();
    }
```

Now if I run the app and click the textbox the OnScreen-Display comes up with the paste symbol. I can repeatedly press the paste-button until counter shows 32000. One more click on the paste symbol crashes the app. It happens in the Visual Studio emulator and also on my real Windows Phone.
I believe it must be a glitch in the pasting mechanism but I could also be completely wrong. Is it really only me?

Update3: After some tests it looks now like a "Umlaut" problem (äöü are german Umlauts). If I add following line to the code of @f14shm4n before(!) his Append-Loop his code will crash too:

```
    sb.Append("ö");
```

Strange thing is it does not crash with "ä" or "ü", only with "ö". It also does not crash if I move this line after(!) the Append-Loop.
Can other people confirm this behaviour or is it again only me?

Update 4: Bug message
System.Exception was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

-$exception {System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.TextBox_GetRectFromCharacterIndex(DependencyObject sender, UInt32 charIndex, Boolean trailingEdge)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(Int32 charIndex, Boolean trailingEdge)
   at System.Windows.Controls.SipHelper.AdjustFrame(FrameworkElement element, Double bottomMargin, Double& stillObscured)
   at System.Windows.Controls.SipHelper.SelectionChanged(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)} System.Exception

Comment: If the `textbox` has no limit, maybe your problem came cause you're doing it at once. Why don't you try to split the code to put the text inside it in two steps and tell us?

Comment: @BtcSources: if that's the solution, it must be done by the user, not by the programmer.

Comment: Is the limit 32000 or 32767 (working) / 32768 (not working)?

Comment: Can you clarify what "code crashes" means? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @ThomasWeller you've both options, to tell the user the limit, or to bypass it at code and let the user have a better experience (comfort, possibilities, etc). It's your choose, not a must.

Comment: Split the code? How? User press the Paste-Button, clipboard-text is inserted into textbox and crashes if longer than 32000 chars. Sidenote: Clipboard.GetText is blocked on Windows Phone (for safety reasons), so I must lead the user to press the paste symbol.

Comment: @BtcSources: how to bypass it on code level?

Comment: I tested your code with 38000+ chars and it work for me. No crash, but any actions with UI and this long text will be very slowly. And bearing in mind the fact that the TextBox size can not be more than 2048x2048 pixels, TextBox can't display any very long text.

Comment: @f14shm4n: Have You really tested it with the paste-button of the OnScreen-display or just pasting by code? I'm aware of the 2048 size limit and afaik the width of the textblock inside the textbox can be larger, it's just not displayed beyond 2048 pixel.

Comment: I test your first part of code (where using TextChanged event), I think it refers to the code above `The code crashes if I'm pasting more than 32000 chars into the TextBox.` Or you mean OnScreen-keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

What I'm do:

```
    private void b1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 10000;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(i.ToString());
        }

        DBG.WriteLine("SBLength: " + sb.Length);
        Clipboard.SetText(sb.ToString());
    }
```

1) This code generated long text with length = 38890 chars and set it text to Clipboard (as in your code).

2) Then I tap on editable area in TextBox, opening OnScreen-keyboard.

3) Tap on past button icon.

**Result:** All text in clipboard pasted in first TextBox, when fired TextChanged event, second TextBox(or TextBlock nevermind) update Text property and show 38890. This is write ? :)

Comment: thx a lot for your help, things become clearer. Can you confirm my new conclusion from my Update3?

Comment: Strange, but I had no problem with umlauts chars, all works fine.

Comment: Then it must be a strange kind of localization problem. I have added the error message. Maybe someone want to dig it, for me it's too high.